# How can I compare if two types are equal using preprocessor directives?

Tags: c++, preprocessor

I have a class that allows for dynamically setting specific values. It has multiple constructors in the following way:

```cpp
class Property {
  enum PropertyType { INT32, UINT32, UINT64, OBJECTSIZE, ... };
public:
  Property(int32_t value_) : type(INT32), value(value_) {}
  Property(uint32_t value_) : type(UINT32), value(value_) {}
  Property(uint64_t value_) : type(UINT64), value(value_) {}
  Property(size_t value_) : type(OBJECTSIZE), value(value_) {}

private:
  std::any value;
  PropertyType type;
};
```

This works really well except for one part. Depending on compiler, `size_t` value can be a different type. For example, on macOS with clang, `size_t` is a custom type while on Linux with GCC, `size_t` is `uint64_t`. As a result, I am getting compiler error due to conflicting types between two constructors.

Is there a way that I can add a preprocessor condition to disable `size_t` constructor if the types match? Something like:

```cpp
#if uint64_t != size_t or uint32_t != size_t
  Property(size_t value_) : type(OBJECTSIZE), value(value_) {}
#endif
```

Comment: Sorry, no, C++ does not work this way. The preprocessing phase happens before anything about the structure of the C++ code, what all the classes and types are, are even known. Additionally, you will likely discover that your `size_t` is just an alias for either `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`, and is completely indistinguishable from its alter-ego, so you don't need `OBJECTSIZE` anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the information! What confused me was that `size_t` had a completely different type in Xcode (clang). I refactored my code and converted some `size_t`'s to `uint64_t` when passing them to Property object, which works well for my use-case.

Comment: You can't solve this with preprocessor macros, but possibly with SFINAE using `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same/_v`

Answer (score 1):

> How can I compare if two types are equal using preprocessor directives?

You can't - preprocessor is not aware of types.

> This works really well except for one part.

Use SFINAE to disable the overload when `size_t` is the same as the others.